# cat: pid.txt: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, cat, ps

I have a problem with cat. I want to write script doing the same thing as ps -e. In pid.txt i have PID of running processes.

```
ls /proc/ | grep -o "[0-9]" | sort -h > pid.txt
```

Then i want use $line like a part of path to cmdline for evry PID.

```
cat pid.txt | while read line; do cat /proc/$line/cmdline; done
```

i try for loop too

```
for id in 'ls /proc/ | grep -o "[0-9]\+" | sort -h'; do 
cat /proc/$id/cmdline;
done
```

Don't know what i'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the output of just `ls /proc/` present you with...?

Comment: If you must use `ls`, then use `ls -1 /proc/` and don't use `grep -o` but just `grep '[0-9]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're after is this - there were a few flaws with all of your approaches (or did you really just want to look at process with a single-digit PID?):

```
for pid in $(ls /proc/ | grep -E '^[0-9]+$'|sort -h); do cat /proc/${pid}/cmdline; tr '\x00' '\n'; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be in a **different current directory** when running `cat pid.txt...` command compared to when you ran your `ls...` command. Run both your commands on the same terminal window, or use absolute path, like `/path/to/pid.txt`

Other than your error, you might wanna remove `-o` from your grep command as it gives you 1 digit for a matching pid. For example, you get 2 when pid is 423. @Roadowl also pointed that already.